# No podspec found for `React` in `../node_modules/react-native`

Tags: react-native, path

No podspec found for `React` in `../node_modules/react-native`

I am getting above error when i do pod install after successful npm install

NPM Version : 5.6.0
Below is the pod file text

```
# Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
# but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
react_native_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'Yoga', :path => "#{react_native_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
pod 'React', :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
'Core',
'RCTText',
'RCTImage',
'DevSupport',
'BatchedBridge',
'RCTLinkingIOS',
'RCTAnimation',
'RCTActionSheet',
'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
# Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
]
```

end

Comment: React POD has been deprecated a few versions ago ( i think it was 11 ) you can safely remove reacts pod entry

Comment: @funkysoul, where you find such information? As I can see, only **published** to cocoapods deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Check that file `../node_modules/react-native/React.podspec` is really exists relative to `Podfile`. If not, check that you `package.json` really contain `react-native` as dependency.

For standard RN project directory structure, Podfile should be placed in `<projectRoot>/ios/Podfile`, and looks like:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CGUI' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'DevSupport',
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
end
```

This is for RN 0.51.0

Answer (score 3):

1. after successful npm install,
2. delete the file podfile.lock in your project root dir,
3. then pod install in your project root dir.

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory
in IOS write command in terminal to open Xcode

```
open ios/[projectname].xcworkspace
```

and open **Pods** folder from the left navigation bar and open **Profile** file
after that remove the line,

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

and rebuild project.